# Bring back deleted posts - Facebook Graph / FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have got another facebook Graph related question. Is it possible to get deleted posts from Facebook Graph API, all those posts that are wiped out from me/feed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The API gets the information from Facebook just like if it were you.